# Excel 365 Function to Count Occurrence of Array List In Original List

Tags: arrays, excel, count, formula

I have a list of company names in the sheet "Defects". I built a unique list of those companies in a sheet called "Report" using this function utilizing an array list.

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(Defects!E:E,,TRUE),,1)
```

This works great. Since the array is dynamic, it can grow and shrink. I want to do a count of the number of times a single item from the array appears in the "Defects" sheet.

In the "Defects" sheet This is my complete list

```
  E     
1 Acme        
2 Gadget
3 Widget      
4 Acme
5 Widget
6 Widget
```

This is what I want in the "Report" sheet.

```
  Company     Count 
1 Acme        2
2 Gadget      1
3 Widget      3
```

I can't seem to make a function that will take a specific value in the array as an input as a COUNT or COUNTIF function. This function gives me all values of 1.

```
=COUNT(MATCH(A20,Defects!E:E,0))
```

A simple COUNTIF gives me an error and turns the formula into text.

```
=COUNTIF(Defects!E:E,A1))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LET and CHOOSE with COUNTIFS:

```
=LET(x,SORT(UNIQUE(E1:E6)),CHOOSE({1,2},x,COUNTIFS(E:E,x)))
```

[image]

Or if you really want full column references:

```
=LET(y,E:E,x,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(y,y<>""))),CHOOSE({1,2},x,COUNTIFS(y,x)))
```

Comment: Holy Crap that's awesome! This is looking more and more like a cludgy SQL. Wish we could combine the two. Awesome answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Scott's answer is obviously the way to go, doing the whole thing in a single formula, but to answer the part of your question that is about how to make Countif look at an array for its criteria rather than a single value:

Suppose you have a working spill formula for the unique values like

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(Defects!E:E,Defects!E:E<>"")))
```

in A1,

then to reference all of its values as an array in another formula you just have to put a hash on the end of its reference:

```
=COUNTIF(Defects!E:E,A1#)
```

[image]

[See documentation here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/spilled-range-operator-3dd5899f-bca2-4b9d-a172-3eae9ac22efd)

Comment: I had a lot of problems with this. I got @Scott's answer to work. For some reason I'm not making some sort of connection. I'll need to study more, but I appreciate all the help. In SQL this is a straightforward solution. Obviously, I'm used to SQL.